# Cannot uninstall node

Tags: node.js, macos

I have followed several comprehensive guides on how to remove node from the machine, but nothing is working, and when I run `node --version`, it still shows to be on my machine.

I have followed https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-completely-uninstall-Node-js-from-MacOS and ran every command, but still node persists on my machine.

Is there a way to find where node is installed? `whereis node` returns nothing

Comment: `which node` to find where node is installed.

Comment: ahh, you are a life saver. It was installed under `.nvm` for future reference to anyone who may stumble upon this post. I hadn't properly understood that nvm could actually hold node

Answer (score 2):

Find the node using `which node` then use `sudo rm node` to remove the package.